# Java - Newly created file on smb share has no user, no group

Tags: java, file-permissions, smb

I mounted a SMB share via fstab:

```
//IP_SERVER/public /home/sl/images_server cifs username=USER,passwd=PASSWD 0 0
```

I want to create some new files in /home/sl/images_server. The folder has the mod 777 and the user and group sl.

When I try to save a file via Java I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/sl/images_server/test.jpg (Permission denied)
```

I use the following code to write the image:

```
ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(SOURCE_FILE), "jpg", new File("/home/sl/images_server/test.jpg"));
```

After I executed the Java command I see a newly created file in the folder with nobody as user, nogroup as group and '-rw-r--r--' as mod.

What is neccessary to save a file in this folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem has nothing to do with Java. It was just my samba server which wasn't configured well.

See this for more informations.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/97669/i-cant-get-samba-to-set-proper-permissions-on-created-directories